# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am executing below SQL Script which is throwing error **Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime**

I have searched for this error in SO and google but I'm  not able to figure out the solution.

Below is mine Longggggggggg SQL Query

```
DECLARE @TimeByDay DATETIME 
DECLARE @TimeByDay2 DATETIME

SET @TimeByDay = '1/1/2012'
SET @TimeByDay2 = '12/31/2014'


SELECT  p1.ProjectName ,
        p1.EnterpriseProjectTypeName ,
        p1.[Legacy System ID] ,
        p1.ProjectDescription ,
        p1.ProjectOwnerName ,
        p1.[Gate Approvers] ,
        p1.[Team Members] ,
        p1.[Project Sponsor] ,
        p1.[Idea Project Type] ,
        p1.[Compliance Project] ,
        p1.[Product Category] ,
        p1.[Relevant Functional Area] ,
        p1.Initiative ,
        p1.[OPEX Transformation] ,
        p1.[Commodity Type] ,
        p1.[LSS Training Project] ,
        p1.[Project Status Comments] ,
        p1.[Project Status] ,
        p1.Phase ,
        p1.[Innovation Matrix Class] ,
        p1.[Legacy Project Manager] ,
        p1.[AOP Line Number] ,
        p1.[AOP Project Name] ,
        p1.[Approval Level] ,
        p1.Assumptions ,
        p1.[Belt Name] ,
        p1.[Benefits Impact] ,
        p1.[Bus Impact or Bus Y] ,
        p1.[Business Sponsor] ,
        p1.[Code Name] ,
        p1.[Complexity Risk Level] ,
        p1.[Complexity Risk Score] ,
        p1.[Critical to Quality] ,
        p1.Deliverables ,
        p1.[Development Risk] ,
        p1.[Estimated Duration] ,
        p1.[Financial Uncertainty] ,
        p1.[Financial Rep] ,
        p1.[External Dependencies] ,
        p1.[Financial Risk Level] ,
        p1.[Financial Risk Score] ,
        p1.[Idea Functional Area] ,
        p1.[Idea Beneftting Location] ,
        p1.[Idea Reviewer Comments] ,
        p1.[Idea Comments] ,
        p1.[Idea Sector] ,
        p1.[Idea Submitters Email] ,
        p1.[Idea Submission Date] ,
        p1.[Idea Submitter Phone] ,
        p1.[Idea Reviewer Name] ,
        p1.[Idea Description_] ,
        p1.[Idea Est Revenue Benefit] ,
        p1.[Idea Name] ,
        p1.[Idea Product Category] ,
        p1.[Idea Est Savings Benefit] ,
        p1.[Idea Number] ,
        p1.[Idea Review Date] ,
        p1.[Idea Est Balance Sheet Benefit] ,
        p1.[Idea Est Investment] ,
        p1.[Idea Submitter Email] ,
        p1.[IR Project Type] ,
        p1.[Idea Sources] ,
        p1.[Idea Submitter] ,
        p1.[Implementation Risk] ,
        p1.[Technology Capabilities Risk] ,
        p1.[Market Uncertainty] ,
        p1.[Legal Regulatory Risk] ,
        p1.[Investment Risk] ,
        p1.Mentor ,
        p1.[Out of Scope] ,
        p1.[Project Scope] ,
        p1.[Project Start Date] ,
        p1.[Project Finish Date] ,
        p1.[Mandated by whom?] ,
        p1.[Reason for Action] ,
        p1.[Project Champion] ,
        p1.[Process Owner] ,
        p1.[Target State (Box 3 of A3)] ,
        p1.[Problem Statement] ,
        p1.[Project Interaction] ,
        p1.[Strategic Goal/Business Case] ,
        p1.[Sending Leader(s)] ,
        p1.[Receiving Leader(s)] ,
        p1.[Process Definition] ,
        p1.[Things That Can Be Improved] ,
        p1.[Idea Estimated Duration] ,
        p1.[ST IT Cost Center] ,
        p1.[Top Project] ,
        p1.[Reason For Action (Box 1 of A3)] ,
        p1.[Initial State] ,
        p1.[Impact of not meeting mandate] ,
        p1.[Primary Proponent Department] ,
        p1.[Project Financial Benefit Status] ,
        p1.[Project Resource Status] ,
        p1.[Project Schedule Status] ,
        p1.[Project Investment Status] ,
        p1.[Project Success Factors] ,
        p1.[Support Required] ,
        p1.[Project Milestones] ,
        p1.[Project Constraints] ,
        p1.[Other Funding Source] ,
        p1.[Project Cost Center] ,
        p1.[Initial State (Box 2 of A3)] ,
        p1.CostCenterName ,
        p1.CostCategoryName ,
        YEAR(p1.TimeByDay) AS Year ,
        MONTH(p1.TimeByDay) AS Month ,
        p1.Actuals ,
        p1.Budget ,
        p1.Forecast ,
        p1.PhaseName ,
        p1.ProjectUID ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), p1.ProjectCreatedDate, 101) AS ProjectCreatedDate ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), p1.ProjectModifiedDate, 101) AS ProjectModifiedDate
FROM    [IR.ST.EPM Custom Flds and Financial Data] p1
--WHERE   p1.TimeByDay >= CAST(@TimeByDay AS DATETIME)
--        AND p1.TimeByDay <= CAST(@TimeByDay2 AS DATETIME)
WHERE p1.timebyday >= @TimeByDay
        AND p1.timebyday <=@TimeByDay2
        AND p1.StageEntryDate IS NOT NULL
        AND p1.StageCompletionDate IS NOT NULL
```

I'm not sure what needs to be change here.

Sorry for duplicate!

Comment: is your timebyday field in your table a datetime field?

Comment: make sure, all the datetime related columns are in `datetime` datatype. otherwise, there must be some data which is out of date range.

Comment: @bluefeet - The TimeByDay is DATETIME in database

Comment: Firstly, is `[IR.ST.EPM Custom Flds and Financial Data]` a view or a table? If it is a view does this run as `SELECT *` (to elimiate the error not originating in the code you have posted. Your next check should be does the `SELECT *` run with the `WHERE` clause, if it does then you know your error is in the `WHERE` clause. If this works, then start adding the select columns in 1 at a time until you get the error. This will enable you to isolate the column that is causing the error. This will allow you to post more information that could help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the start of your script where you assign strings to `DATETIMEs`.  This involves an *implicit* conversion, as if the RDBMS adds the `CONVERT()` in there for you.  And in your case it's failing.

Try a more universal date-time format instead...

```
SET @TimeByDay  = '20120101'
SET @TimeByDay2 = '20141231'
```

Comment: That didn't worked. Moreover the user would enter the dates in US format (as specified in the question)

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - If the strings are user supplied, I'd recommend converting the to a date data-type in your application, before supplying them to SQL Server as DATETIME parameters.  This prevents SQL Injection and ensures data validity.  But that's a side issue for now it seems.  *[And also not actually mentioned in your question ;)]*

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - To narrow things down...  If you just run the DECLARE and SET statements, do they definitely work?  If not, does `CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/2014', 101)` help?  And what data types is the `TimeByDay` field?

Comment: The datatype of TimeByDay (in database) is DATETIME

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - Did testing just the DECLARE and SET show that they're not the source of the error message?  And/Or did the `CONVERT()` example help at all?  Another (longshot) could be to check the datatypes for the ProjectCreatedDate and ProjectModifiedDate fields?

Comment: ProjectCreatedDate & ProjectModifiedDate both are of DATETIME datatype

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - Have you testing the DECLARE and SET section without the SELECT query yet?  It's sounding more and more likely that the error is there.  To isolate or eliminate that possibility, could you test just that section on it's own?

Comment: I just test the SQL Query by using only DECLARE & SET section. The commands completed successfully.

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. - Is this your exact query?  From everything you've told us, there is no source for the error.